# Is &self parameter necessary in the function of trait?

Tags: rust, traits

Looking this example code

```rust
trait Animal {
    fn make_sound(&self);
}

struct Dog;
impl Animal for Dog {
    fn make_sound(&self) {
        println!("Woof!");
    }
}

struct Cat;
impl Animal for Cat {
    fn make_sound(&self) {
        println!("Meow!");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let dog = Dog;
    let cat = Cat;
    dog.make_sound();
    cat.make_sound();
}
```

The function(method) `make_sound()` is just print a string.

I check the content of this function, `make_sound()` does not seems to invoke any information of `Cat` struct.

So I tried to remove `&self` parameter, but could not get the pass compiler.

Is &self necessary in the function of trait? Why?

Or where is my understanding wrong?

### Edit: Add code which could not get the pass compiler

```
trait Animal {
    fn make_sound();
}

struct Dog;
impl Animal for Dog {
    fn make_sound() {
        println!("Woof!");
    }
}

struct Cat;
impl Animal for Cat {
    fn make_sound() {
        println!("Meow!");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let dog = Dog;
    let cat = Cat;
    dog.make_sound();
    cat.make_sound();
}
```

Comment: A trait function without a `self` is called an *associated* function. And you can think of it being like `static` in Java. You call it on the trait, not on a particular instance, and there's different syntax to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, a `self` parameter is not required for trait functions. However, if there is no `self` parameter, you can't use the `obj.func()` syntax since there is no instance to be provided. You have to do `Type::func()`:

```
trait Animal {
    fn make_sound();
}

struct Dog;
impl Animal for Dog {
    fn make_sound() {
        println!("Woof!");
    }
}

struct Cat;
impl Animal for Cat {
    fn make_sound() {
        println!("Meow!");
    }
}

fn main() {
    Dog::make_sound();
    Cat::make_sound();
}
```

```
Woof!
Meow!
```

Comment: And to call a free function of a trait, inside another function of the trait you can do `Self::func()`

Comment: However the `self` parameter is required to disambiguate when using `dyn` like in: `fn poke (animal: &dyn Animal) { animal.make_sound(); }` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=a04ec2f612cd33eb47ffd1aa0c866f8d))